# Autoselection for gmx trjcat using bash shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I would like to auto select `c` for continue for `gmx trjcat`. The following command was used:

`echo 'c c c c c' | gmx trjcat -f trajectory1.xtc trajectory2.xtc trajectory3.xtc trajectory4.xtc trajectory5.xtc -n index.ndx -o output.xtc -settime`

When running this command I get

> Fatal error: Error reading user input

How can I adjust the command to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works: `echo -e "c\nc\nc\nc\nc"` (give a break line for each `c`)

Comment: `printf '%s\n' c c c c c` is better than `echo -e`.  Or use `yes c | gmx trjcat ...` if an unknown number of `c\n` input lines is required (`yes` will continue printing "c" and a newline to stdout as long as there's something to consume it - e.g. a pipe to another program, or the terminal if there's no pipe).   This assumes that `gmx` actually accepts `c` or other commands from stdin - if it doesn't, you'll have to write a tcl [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/), perl [Expect.pm](https://metacpan.org/dist/Expect), python [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) or similar script.